# How to properly execute C# file over local network?

Tags: c#, php, javascript

Overview

C# File - Users PC
PHP Server - Hosts Webpages for application

Server and Users PC on local network

I have a c# file that reads weight from a USB scale.  How would I trigger this file to run so it feeds into my program.  The problem is I am using PHP to host our webpage/application so its not running client side and the scale is not hooked up to the server but to the clients PC.

The C# script would have to be on the clients in order to read the scale so how would I trigger this to happen?

Is this even possible and if not what would be a better way?

****Important Edit****
I was able to run the Scale Script (C#) when I wanted by having PHP and C# use TCP sockets.

The C# would listen for PHP to send something and when it did it would read the scale and send this information back to PHP becuase PHP was listening for a response.  Mixed in with a little Ajax and it updates in the web browser.

Gave Chris Credit because he was the most helpful with answering my questions

Comment: With "C# file" do you mean a `*.cs` file, or an executable?

Comment: What do you mean by "C# File"? An assembly (dll) or an executable (exe)? Did you just type C# Code in a txt file?

Comment: Given PHP runs under the machine's context, you're either going to need to allow permissions on the other machine for PHP to access a remote resource, or find a way for PHP to run with a network authority so it can access the other machine's resources.

Comment: Sorry I am very new to C# and was given this script from ConnectShip.  I had to include 2 dll files, Progistics.API.dll and Progistics.Devices.dll.  I have it originally saved as a .cs but also saved it as a console application to get it to execute...Sorry never used C# before but need it for this particular scenario

Comment: @Bobby It isn't a script, it's the source code for that console application. C# isn't a scripting language. See answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you really want is for the client application to *submit* the data to the website itself, and the most suitable approach is probably to expose a web service from your server.

This service should accept weight data, along with some sort of customer key or whatever, to correlate the records correctly on the server side. I've never created a web service in PHP personally, so I can't give any advice on the implementation of that, but it is fairly trivial to hook a C# client app up to a web service once you've exposed its metadata (assuming you use SOAP).

Comment: I think what your saying is what I am truly looking for.  I need the client application to read the weight and then submit it to my server.

Comment: @Bobby: How far have you gotten so far with the client application? Does it read the data you need? If so, you should do some research into exposing web services from PHP - there are various approaches you could take, but make your decision based on security requirements, scalability etc. Once you've gotten some sort of service up and running, it should be simple enough to update the C# client app to upload the weight results. I presume your service would then save the submission to your MySQL tables.

Comment: All I have is a simple source code that ConnectShip gave me that displays the weight to the console and thats it.  I have nothing else becuase I was not sure where to go.  From what it looks like my only option is to somehow have this run every few seconds and update a mySQL table so PHP can grab its value.

Comment: @Bobby: You don't want this client to be directly updating your database. Like I mentioned above, this is a textbook use case for web services. Research PHP web services, perhaps this link is a good start; http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json. Once you have a handle on how to submit data via this service, then it would be time to tackle the client app.

Comment: How it works now is that it gets the scales weight and submits (POST) the data to a PHP file.  What I need to do now is somehow figure out how to make this script run on its own.  I do not want the script to be run manually becuase that would be counter productive (They can just look at the scale and enter weight themselves).  Is there anyway to make this script run every second? or any other suggestions?

Comment: @Bobby: Perhaps write a Windows service that you get your user to install on their machine. Have this service manage the execution of the "Weighing" program according to your required schedule. You've mentioned that the client app POSTs to a PHP file. What happens then, what does this PHP script do? If it writes to a DB, then you can consider your PHP file to be somewhat analogous to the suggestion to use a web service. The difference being, you do not want DB writing code sitting on client machines.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6898/discussion-between-bobby-and-chris-mcatackney)

Answer (score 2):

C# isn't a scripting language, it's a language that compiles into executable binaries or libraries. You won't be able to execute C# code on the client's computer via a website because C# code needs to be compiled before it can run.

Presumably what you really want is for your compiled C# binary to be executed on the client's machine via your website. You won't be able to easily do that. There are a lot of security measures in place to prevent browsers from running programs on your computer. There may be ways to hack around these security measures by using plugins (such as ActiveX), but it's not something that will be a one-liner.

**Edit:** I think you need to step back and think about what you're trying to do in a broad sense. You're trying to create a website that can read information from a user's USB port. This is the type of thing that browsers are designed to *prevent*, and for good reason. I wouldn't want random websites to be able to access peripheral hardware without my explicit permission. If you want this website to function the way you're expecting, you're going to have to seriously think about the security implications. You'll need some kind of client-side code (ActiveX, Silverlight, ...), and the user will need to explicitly give permission to for this all to happen. It won't be easy, and it won't be automatic. And I'm damn glad that's true.

Comment: Yeah I know what I am asking seems ridiculous.  But what I was hoping was to somehow save this source code on each of the clients PC and execute it when I needed it to give me the data.  The data doesn't even have to go into PHP but maybe into a mySQL table and I can have PHP pull it from there.

Answer (score 2):

you can't start C# application from a web page in a way that'll work in every browser every time. BUT, you can have some workarounds:

- Use ActiveX component that read the data in the client and upload it to the server. the biggest cons is that it'll only work in Internet Explorer
- use Silverlight client application that runs on elevated mode (v4) and upload the data to your server.
- refer your clients to download application (the C# application you wrote about) and run it - this application will upload the data to your server.

hope this helps.

Comment: I think you should stick with the third suggestion here. Just add any kind of data submission feature to your tool.

Comment: what about this.  Is there anyway to have the user start up the script and have it keep running say every few seconds to keep grabbing the weight and update a mySQL table?  Then my web program can just pull that data from there?